# How to cut every line from a particular string?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, ksh

**input.txt:**

```
john_Apple01_xyz_1
john_Fruit_Apple01_abc_c1
john_Apple21_trs_1
john_Fruit_Apple21_efg_1
john_Fruit_Apple21_tefg_1
```

**Desired output:**

```
Apple01_xyz_1
Apple01_abc_c1
Apple21_trs_1
Apple21_efg_1
Apple21_tefg_1
```

How to use nawk or sed to cut the leading portion everytime the Apple is found in the line ?

i'm using KSH in Solaris 10.

Comment: `sed -e 's/.*\(Apple\)/\1/'`

Comment: @cuonglm are you going to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@cuonglm's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258597/how-to-cut-every-line-from-a-particular-string#comment447290_258597) illustrates how you can do this with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/.*\(Apple\)/\1/' input.txt
```

You might also consider using good old `grep`:

```
grep -o 'Apple.*' input.txt
```

Caveat 1 - I don't have any solaris handy, so it might be that the solaris `grep` doesn't have the `-o` option.  YMMV.

Caveat 2 - If your input file has lines that don't contain any `Apple`s at all, then these won't appear in the output at all.  Not sure if that is the behavior you want.  If not, then the `sed` answer will suffice.

Comment: isn't `-o` GNU grep-specific? I don't think that would be available by default in OP's Solaris env

Comment: @1_CR Not sure - I don't have any solaris handy.  The BSD `grep` on OS X *does* have this option though.  I suppose I should download a [VM image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/vmtemplates-vmvirtualbox-1949721.html) - that'll have to wait until later.

Comment: @cuonglm if you want to add the `sed` answer, I'll happily edit it out from here - its your's for the taking :)

Comment: [Probably not](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/grep-1.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Both solutions work, however my solaris 5.10 grep or egrep does not have -o option. So i found alternate way to this, i found ggrep located in  /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -o 'Apple.*'   and it worked fine. i always find this ggrep useful but i don't understand why i cant use ggrep directly. Whenever i want to use it, i have to give full path for ggrep

Comment: @ayrton_senna because your path doesn't include the directory where ggrep lives. The correct solution is to add a link in /bin, similar to this: `link -s //usr/sfw/bin/ggrep /bin/ggrep`. Or some other PATHed directory you preffer.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I was able to add soft link to ggrep and use it anywhere in my system, however there is no MAN page entry for ggrep.

Comment: @ayrton_senna http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/ggrep/

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thank you, but i would like to add this man page to my system instead of looking up everytime. Is that possible ?

Comment: @ayrton_senna I would start with `find /usr/sfw -name 'grep.1*'` to locate the file.  If its not there, then download http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/grep-2.2.tar.gz (or whatever version from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/), then untar the man file `tar -x grep-2.2/src/grep.1 < grep-2.2.tar.gz` and load the page directly from the file `man grep-2.2/src/grep.1`.  YMMV - tested on OSX and not solaris.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for `nawk` or `sed`.  As you mention `ksh`, why not do a pure shell version?

The following runs in any POSIX compliant shell:

```
p="Apple"
while read line ; do
  case $line in
  (*$p*) echo $p${line#*$p};;
  esac
done <<!
john_Apple01_xyz_1
john_Fruit_Apple01_abc_c1
john_Apple21_trs_1
john_Fruit_Apple21_efg_1
john_Fruit_Apple21_tefg_1
!
```

This results in:

```
Apple01_xyz_1
Apple01_abc_c1
Apple21_trs_1
Apple21_efg_1
Apple21_tefg_1
```

*pure shell*